# recovering values using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to process a bilingual xml file using xsl but there is clearly an issue with my loop. The purpose is to copy value of each of my nodes next its translation on my style-sheet ie: apple -> pomme (see the expected output below)

**My input file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="reinsert.xsl"?>

<translate>
  <extract count="1">bonjour</extract>
  <extract count="2">pomme</extract>
</translate>
```

**My output file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
  <file source-language="fr" datatype="plaintext" target-language="en">
    <body>
      <trans-unit approved="yes" id="1">
        <source>hi</source>
        <target>bonjour</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit approved="yes" id="2">
        <source>Apple2</source>
        <target>bonjour</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit approved="yes" id="1">
        <source>hi</source>
        <target>pomme</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit approved="yes" id="2">
        <source>Apple2</source>
        <target>pomme</target>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

**Expected output**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
  <file source-language="fr" datatype="plaintext" target-language="en">
    <body>
      <trans-unit approved="yes" id="1">
        <source>hi</source>
        <target>bonjour</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit approved="yes" id="2">
        <source>Apple</source>
        <target>pomme</target>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

my stylesheet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
 <xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
  <file source-language="fr" datatype="plaintext" target-language="en">
    <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="/translate/extract">
            <trans-unit xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:space="preserve" approved="yes" id="1">

                <source>hi</source>
                <target>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
                </target>

            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:space="preserve" approved="yes" id="2">
                <source>Apple</source>
                <target>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
                </target>

            </trans-unit>

  </xsl:for-each>  
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Many thanks !

Comment: Can you share your stylesheet?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What/where is the file you call "My output file"? It seems like this needs to be an additional **input** to the XSL Transformation process, along with the "My input file" file and the stylesheet itself.